# Which meaning of the verb "prescribe" fits in this context?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, terminology

What does the verb ''prescribe'' mean in these sentences?

> two initial conditions$$y(x_{0})=K_{0},\ \ y'(x_{0})=K_{1}$$
> **prescribe** values ${K_0}$ and ${K_1}$ of the solution and its first derivative (the slope of it's curve) at the same point $x=x_{0}$

> one **prescribes** the initial temperature $u(x,0)=f(x)$ (f given) and boundary conditions at x=0 and x=L for all $t\geq 0$ ,for instance,
> $u(0,t) = 0,{\rm{ }}u(L,t) = 0$

> a problem in which T is **prescribed** on one portion of the boundary
> and ${{\partial T} \over {\partial n}}$on the other portion is called a mixed boundary value problem.

> Three given distinct points $z_{1},z_{3},z_{3}$ can always be mapped onto three **prescribed**
> distinct points $w_{1},w_{3},w_{3}$ by one, and only one, linear fractional transformation $w=f(z)={{az+b}\over{cz+d}}$

I searched in all available dictionaries and The only meaning Which seems appropriate is this:
''to specify with authority''

What do you think is the true meaning of this word?

Comment: In all cases it means the value is fixed beforehand and that determines the object that can satistify the requirements. For example, if we are looking at the equation $x=y^2$ and you prescribe that $x=1$, then the only solutions are $y=\pm 1$

Answer (score 2):

The word “prescribe” in each of the given examples really just means *specify*; each “prescription” specifies further *context* for mathematical modelling.

Comment: Is this a proper meaning: ''specify beforehand''?

Comment: @Arashrostami Clearly, the mathematics doesn't care about whether the scenario is past or current or future. In any case, do you think it matters if the specification is given beforehand (before *what*, exactly?) or after? BTW, why are all your questions on this site of the dictionary variety (nothing wrong)? Judging from a quick skim though, perhaps you ought to be more confident of your self-ability to verify (for accuracy), and in fact create, test-definitions; for example, this current word isn't specialist, and is in fact arguably more a general english than mathematics term.